# Getting strange auto layout error

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, swift4

I have a view that i have to hide and resize with this function

```
@objc func dismiss() {
        self.endEditing(true)
        self.isHidden = true

        NewTodoReference.newTodo?.detailsHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
        NewTodoReference.newTodo?.detailsHeightAnchor = NewTodoReference.newTodo?.detailsPopUp.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 46)
        NewTodoReference.newTodo?.detailsHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            NewTodoReference.newTodo?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
}
```

The only problem is that I'm getting this auto layout issues from the debugger:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000286e00 Hippotomo.NewTodoView:0x7ffd6a008c30.height == UIView:0x7ffd68506220.height - 69   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00009d4c0 Hippotomo.WhiteMenuPopUp:0x7ffd6a300c80.height == Hippotomo.NewTodoView:0x7ffd6a008c30.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000288d40 Hippotomo.WhiteMenuPopUp:0x7ffd6a300c80.height == 46   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000283bb0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7ffd68506220.height == 736   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000288d40 Hippotomo.WhiteMenuPopUp:0x7ffd6a300c80.height == 46   (active)>
```

This are all the constraint I've created and that I have to resize

```
var detailsYAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
var detailsWidthAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
var detailsHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
```

This are the original constraints:

```
detailsPopUp.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive
= true

detailsYAnchor = detailsPopUp.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: activityTextfield.bottomAnchor, constant: 17)
detailsYAnchor?.isActive = true

detailsWidthAnchor = detailsPopUp.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, constant:
-32)
detailsWidthAnchor?.isActive = true

detailsHeightAnchor = detailsPopUp.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 46)
detailsHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
```

This is the function that makes my view bigger:

```
func showPopUps(view: UIView, y: NSLayoutConstraint, width: NSLayoutConstraint, height: NSLayoutConstraint) {

        var y = y
        var width = width
        var height = height

        y.isActive = false
        y = view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor)
        y.isActive = true
        width.isActive = false
        width = view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor)
        width.isActive = true
        height.isActive = false
        height = view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor)
        height.isActive = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
}

@objc func presentDetailsPopUp() {
        detailsPopUp.isHidden = false
        showPopUps(view: detailsPopUp, y: detailsYAnchor!, width: detailsWidthAnchor!, height: detailsHeightAnchor!)
        detailsPopUp.textView.becomeFirstResponder()
        detailsPopUp.presentTextView()
    }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is the problem in a table or collection view cell?

Comment: It very hard to read with what little code you have shown. From the debugger:  (1) I'm seeing two height constraints"NewToDoView.height-69" *and* a simple/flat "46". (2) That second constraint is the one being broken. But (of course?) you've already seen this, right? The *actual* issue may well reside with something you probably need to put (please IN your question, not a comment): `NewTodoReference.newTodo?.detailsHeightAnchor?.isActive = false`. What is `NewToDoReference`, `detailsHeightAnchor`, and the initial constraint? *Where* is this constraint defined?

Comment: NewTodoReference.newTodo is a reference to another UIView. DetailsHeightAnchor is the height constraint of the view that i want to resize. Initially it has an height of 46 after I press a button to  make it bigger like another UIView and after with the dismiss button I resize it again with an height of 46

Comment: technically I'm trying to resize a UIView inside another UIView